# Does Ubuntu One have a file size or type limit?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I uploaded a 1.7G .iso file to Ubuntu One, kept tracking for a good while with `u1sdtool`. But when it was uploaded and `u1sdtool` gave feedback that there was no transfer going on, I went and checked my files through the website, it wasn't there. Was that too big or is there limits on file-type such for example .iso file.

Comment: How did you upload this file? Using the desktop client or the webpage? Are you sure that the file has finished uploading (check with the desktop client)? The [FAQ warns](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/can-i-upload-large-files-through-the-web/) about connection interruptions while uploading large files through the website.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's wrong, but according to the [Ubuntu One FAQ](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/):

#### [What is the largest size file I can sync with Ubuntu One?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-is-the-largest-size-file-i-can-sync-with-ubuntu-one/)

> 5 TB is currently the largest size file you can sync with Ubuntu One.